# Gravitational potential energy lost by an object falling on the earth

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, potential, potential-energy

I am stuck on this simple question:

> *g* is the strength of the gravitational field at the surface of the
>   Earth; *R* is the radius of the Earth. Show an equation describing the
>   potential energy lost by a satellite of mass *m* falling to the Earth’s
>   surface from a height R above the surface.

This is what I did to solve the problem (the answer is wrong)
V1 = -GM/2R; V2 = -GM/R

V1 - V2 = (-GM/2R) - (-GM/R) = GM/2R

therefore change in energy = GMm/2R; where *m* = mass of object.

This can also be rewritten as mgR/2.  My book says it should be 2mgR

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, your book is incorrect.

You can convince yourself of this by considering the following:

The work required to move a mass $m$ from the surface of the earth a small height $h$ is $mgh$. The greater $h$ is, the smaller $g$ will become, and therefore $mgR$ provides an *upper bound* on the work required to lift the mass a height $R$, and so it can't possibly be $2mgR$.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense indeed, the question was an official exam paper so I thought I was mistaken.